# Yesod - Extract session data (non-String), store it and use it

Tags: haskell, yesod

#### Hi there.

Here is the code I'm trying to make work :

```
getGameR :: Handler Html
getGameR = do
    sess <- getSession
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle "Game"
        $(widgetFile "hamletFile")
    where
        person = read $ fromJust $ Map.lookup "person" sess :: Person

data Person = Person
    {
        name :: Text
    }
    deriving (Show, Read)
```

The error is the following:

```
Handler/MyHandler.hs:87:56: Not in scope: `sess'
```

What I'm trying to do, is to extract data from Yesod Session (data of type Person) and store it inside 'person', to be able to use it inside the hamlet file.

Is there a way to get around that error?

If it's not possible, can you suggest another way around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sess` is local to the `do` block, and thus it is not in scope in the `person` definition. As far as that error goes, using `let` inside the `do` block should be enough:

```
getGameR :: Handler Html
getGameR = do
    sess <- getSession
    let person = read $ fromJust $ Map.lookup "person" sess :: Person
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle "Game"
        $(widgetFile "hamletFile")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to lookup single value, consider using `lookupSession` instead. Also, `fromJust` throws exception if key is not in session, you might use `fromMaybe`:

```
getGameR :: Handler Html
getGameR = do
    mbPersonName <- lookupSession "person"
    let defaultPerson = Person "anonymous"
    let person = fromMaybe defaultPerson (readMaybe .unpack =<< mbPersonName) :: Person
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle "Game"
        $(widgetFile "hamletFile")
```

Here is my helpers for dealing with session:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

readSession :: Read a => Text -> Handler (Maybe a)
readSession name = do
    textValue <- lookupSession name
    return (readMaybe . unpack =<< textValue)

readSessionDef :: Read a => a -> Text -> Handler a
readSessionDef def name =  do
    mbValue <- readSession name
    return $ fromMaybe def mbValue
```

`readSession` reads anything that can be readden and returns a `Maybe`. `readSessionDef` returns default value if such key is not present in session:

```
getGameR :: Handler Html
getGameR = do
    person <- readSessionDef (Person "anonymous") "person"
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitle "Game"
        $(widgetFile "hamletFile")
```